# Usage of the word 'have'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

1. *I will soon have a new secretary **work** for me on the weekends.*
2. *I will soon have a new secretary **working** for me on the weekends.*
3. *I will soon have a new secretary **to work** for me on the weekends.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a mixed bag. All three sentences are grammatical, and all three mean more or less the same thing, but they have rather different structures.

(1) is an example of an idiomatic causative construction using *have*.
The pattern is `NP₁` *have* `NP₂ VP`, as in *I had the dealer install a new muffler*.
It means that the dealer installed a new muffler, at my direction.
The verb in the `VP` is an infinitive without *to*: *I had the dealer* (**to) install a new muffler.*
and if it's passive it's without *be* as well: *I had a new muffler* (**to be) installed (by the dealer)*.

(2) is ambiguous, depending on the parse.

- One sense is ordinary 'possess' *have* with the direct object noun phrase
  *a new secretary (who is) working for me on the weekends*.
- Another is a completive construction with *have*.
  `NP₁` *have* `NP₂ X` means '`NP₁` has caused `NP₂` to be in state `X`', as in
  *I'll have the paper finished by tomorrow* or *He has her entering data now.*
  (The use of ***new*** secretary probably makes this interpretation less likely,
  because the meaning implies some period of labor or training prior to success.)

(3) is a completely different construction;  *to work for me on the weekends* is a **purpose** infinitive:
*I will soon have a new secretary (in order for her) to work for me on the weekends.*
The subject is deleted in this case, along with its complementizer for, and *in order*.

Note that, as I said at the beginning, they all mean more or less the same thing.
They are merely different ways to arrive at the same description from different viewpoints.

That's the way language works. It isn't that there's one best way to say something --
generally it's easy to find thousands of ways, and mostly it doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

Purdue Owl has a good page on gerunds, participles, and infinitives. https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/04/

Your second sentence includes the gerund "working"; your third sentence contains the infinitive "to work."  These are often interchangeable, as they are here.

The first sentence seems a little less felicitous, though I can't tell you exactly why.